# Submenus disappearing before they can be clicked on touch devices

Tags: html, menu, touch, submenu, twitter-bootstrap-2

When trying to click on a submenu using bootstrap 2.2.2, the submenu will disappear before it can be clicked on a touch device like an iPhone or iPad. Can someone please look at me code and tell me why?

I thought this was supposed to have been fixed in the latest release, so I'm thinking perhaps I'm missing something in my code.

Menu code:

```
<!-- navbar -->
      <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
          <div class="container">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="brand" href="../home.html">TobyFCU</a>
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav">
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Membership<b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a tabindex="-1" href="#"><strong>Member Benefits &amp; Services</strong></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="membership/benefitsandservices/55plusclub.html">55 Plus Club</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="membership/benefitsandservices/billpay.html">Bill Pay</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Direct Deposit</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="membership/benefitsandservices/foreigncurrency.html">Foreign Currency Exchange</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="membership/benefitsandservices/notary.html">Notary</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="membership/benefitsandservices/onlinebanking.html">Online Banking</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Payroll Deduction</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Toby 24</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">TextME (SMS Banking)</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Western Union Quick Cash</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Wire Transfer</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Toby Rewards</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Other Benefits</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><strong>How to Join</strong></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><strong>SEGs</strong> <small>(<strong>S</strong>elect <strong>E</strong>mployer <strong>G</strong>roups)</small></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><strong>Toby Rewards</strong></a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Personal<b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu"role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a tabindex="-1" href="#"><strong>Loans</strong></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="personal/loans/signatureloans.html">Signature Loans</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="personal/loans/vehicleloans.html">Vehicle Loans</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="personal/loans/mortgages.html">Mortgages</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Home Equity</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Education Loans</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Share Certificate Secured Loan</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Share Secured Loan</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Additional Loans</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Loan Insurance</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><strong>Share Draft Checking</strong></a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a tabindex="-1" href="#"><strong>Savings & CDs</strong></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Share Savings</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Flex/Sub Account</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Club Accounts</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Money Market</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="personal/savingsandcds/sharecertificates.html">Share Certificates</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">IRA Certificate</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">IRA (Traditional & Roth)</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Certificates</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><strong>Credit Card</strong></a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a tabindex="-1" href="#"><strong>Youth</strong></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Student Loans</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Youth Checking</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Youth Visa Check Card</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Student Visa Credit Card</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Toby's Troops</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Toby Teens</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a tabindex="-1" href="#"><strong>Retirement</strong></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Investment Services</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">IRAs</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">55 Plus Club</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><strong>ATMs</strong></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><strong>Rates</strong></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-header">24 Hour Services</li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Online Banking</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Toby24</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TextME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Deluxe Personal Checks Reorder</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ATMs</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Business<b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu"role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                    <li><a href="#"><strong>Loans</strong></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><strong>Share Draft Checking</strong></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><strong>Share Savings</strong></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><strong>Credit Card</strong></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><strong>Certificates</strong></a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a tabindex="-1" href="#"><strong>Services</strong></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Merchant Services</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Payroll Services</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><strong>Rates</strong></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-header">24 Hour Services</li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Online Banking</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">Toby24</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TextME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Deluxe Personal Checks Reorder</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ATMs</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About Us<b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu"role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                    <li><a href="#"><strong>Our Company</strong></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><strong>Careers</strong></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><strong>Blog</strong></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><strong>Locations</strong></a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Contact Us<b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu"role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                    <li><a href="#"><strong>Contact Information</strong></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><strong>Locations</strong></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><strong>ATMs</strong></a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  <!-- /navbar -->
```